# Upgrading Visual Studio 2008 to 2013 and .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am planning a 3pt upgrade for our solution, and it will include an upgrade from VS2008 SP1 to VS2013 and .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1 (and also MS SQL Server 2008 to 2012) I am trying to prepare as much as possible in advance so that I can provide accurate LOEs and make the process as painless as possible. However, I haven't had any luck finding information about how to upgrade a solution from VS2008 to VS2013. For anyone who has done this before, are there any guides you found useful or problems that you faced that you wish you had addressed before hand?

Comment: One possible way to calculate how much time will it take: go ahead and change the target framework (as mentioned in Vincent's answer) and click "Rebuild Solution". The amount of compile errors you get might tell you something about how hard it's going to be.

Comment: I think ultimately it just depends on the product and developers in question. I started with 2010 and found 2012 painless, but some have rejected it completely. I will note that you should probably do it all at once, because the solution conversion isn't backward compatible, though 2010+ is forward compatible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without knowing much (really anything) about your project, it is going to be very hard to give you a straight answer.  However, I can say this.  Microsoft has prided itself since day one on its backwards compatibility.  Simply opening the project in VS 2013 will trigger the upgrade process for the actual SLN.  This is usually quite painless.  Once this is complete, you are still able to target .NET 3.5, so you don't have to make the jump from VS2008 -> VS2013 && NET35 -> NET451 at the same time.

The framework itself shouldn't present you with any serious issues, however any referenced 3rd party dlls can cause (sometimes serious) issues.  They may not be maintained anymore, may have changed names, or simply do not exist.  In this case you will need to find a new library to do what the old one did, which will require refactoring at best, significant rewrite at worst.

None of this takes into account the features ADDED to NET45 from NET35, such as the async/await keywords and many, many, many other features.

Since your question is very vague, its hard to give you a good answer other than just do it, the update to VS2013 should take very little time, and it will tell you if you are going to have issues even building.  Once you do that, it should take no time at all to change your target framework to NET45 or NET451 and find out once again, if you can even compile.  Without doing either of those, you cannot possibly estimate the level of work required.  Then you still have to do all of your testing to see if something changed at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, also your picture is amazing. This man doesn't forget his towel.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not upgrading from Visual Studio 2008 to 2013, because you can still run and compile .NET 3.5 applications in Visual Studio 2013 just fine. The real time consuming process is migrating from .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1 which can be short or long depending on how large is your application and what technology you use.

Usually, .NET 3.5 is very forward compatible.

Changing from one runtime to another (3.5 to 4.5) is simply a matter of changing a setting in your Project (Target Framework).

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that .NET 4.5 is not supported on Windows XP. If your solution needs to run on XP you need to stay on .NET 4.0 or lower.